# Subtracting a date from another date

Tags: sql

I am trying to subtract one date from another but having issues:

```
SELECT MIN(date) AS first_day, 
MAX(date) AS last_date, 
((MAX(date)) - (MIN(date))) AS totaL_days
FROM dates;
```

Could someone please clarify the number format of the number it is returning below?

```
+------------+
| total_days |
+------------+
|   29001900 |
```

I have tried using DATEDIFF but this rounds the days to the nearest whole number and I need to carry out further calculations with the data. The rounding means my solutions are a little off.
In the version of DB I am using DATEDIFF() only takes two parameters so always has to be days as far as I'm aware, I get an error if I try to use hours.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/) - also which data type is the  `date` column a `date` (=only date, **no** time) or a `timestamp` (date **and** time)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF
(
    SELECT MAX(date) FROM dates,
    SELECT MIN(date) FROM dates
)
AS totaL_days;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: So yes this works, but it rounds the answer to a whole number. I am performing calculations with the result of this and need the answer to be more accurate than that.

Comment: Please could you supply a example minimum and maximum datetimes for this query.
In Mariadb, this answer will return results to the nearest microsecond.
You changed the tag, are you no longer using Mariadb?

Comment: How did you eventually solve this please, @NE14ABJ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your RDBMS is a MySql.

Then that number you got would be the seconds between those 2 datetimes.

Because if you subtract 2 DATE types you would get the days between them.

There's [more than DATEDIFF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp) to work with.

**Test data**

> ```
> create table mytest (
>  id int auto_increment primary key, 
>  date_col date not null, 
>  datetime_col datetime not null
> );
>
> insert into mytest(date_col, datetime_col) values
>  ('2021-06-16', '2021-06-16 14:15:30') 
> ,('2021-07-16', '2021-07-16 19:06:15')
> ```

**Test using dates**

> ```
> select 
>   min(date_col) as min_date 
> , max(date_col) as max_date
> , max(date_col) - min(date_col) as subtracted
> , datediff(max(date_col), min(date_col)) as days
> from mytest
> ```
>
> ```
> min_date   | max_date   | subtracted | days
> :--------- | :--------- | ---------: | ---:
> 2021-06-16 | 2021-07-16 |        100 |   30
> ```

**Test using datetimes**

> ```
> select 
>   min(datetime_col) as min_date 
> , max(datetime_col) as max_date
> , max(datetime_col) - min(datetime_col) as seconds
> , datediff(max(datetime_col), min(datetime_col)) as days
> from mytest
> ```
>
> ```
> min_date            | max_date            |   seconds | days
> :------------------ | :------------------ | --------: | ---:
> 2021-06-16 14:15:30 | 2021-07-16 19:06:15 | 100049085 |   30
> ```

**Using sec_to_time and extract**

> ```
> select seconds
> , sec_to_time(seconds) as tm
> , extract(day from sec_to_time(seconds)) as days
> from (
>    select 
>    max(datetime_col) - min(datetime_col) as seconds 
>    from mytest
> ) q
> ```
>
> ```
>   seconds | tm        | days
> --------: | :-------- | ---:
> 100049085 | 838:59:59 |   30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=020901b117dd846595ea616bca4286fe)*